# When using custom scrollbar style on Chrome, a white square appears on lower corner. How to eliminate this?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scrollbar

I have a custom scrollbar style for Chrome on a div. When both scrollbars show, a white square appears on the right lower corner.

```
<div class="scrollbox" id='a'>
    
</div>


body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.scrollbox:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
   background-color: #888;
}

.scrollbox:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  visibility : visible;
   background-color: #666;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

.scrollbox:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
   background-color: #222;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}


var a=document.getElementById('a');
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    a.innerHTML+='<br>'+i + ' aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
}
```

Here is the repro code:
https://codepen.io/nosachamos/pen/xxLOryr

Looks like this:

[image]

How can I make this black so that it won't appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Anything with an alpha of 0 should be invisible, but you can set it to black or a different colour if you please. Tested on Chrome on your Codepen and is working great!

Comment: HA! yes, the scrollbar corner, great! Thank you!

Comment: This is perfect. [CSS is awesome!](https://css-tricks.com/css-is-awesome/)